# Using For Loops instead of If Statement

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

My code selects items from a comboBox by its index number then assigns a specific byte to each item. For this I am using the If statement and am having to repeat it so many times.

I know how to use loops very basically but I haven't got a clue how to do it when each item needs a different value assigned to it.

```
        if (weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            PS3.SetMemory(Offsets.WeaponCamo + (0x80 * (uint)camoclassUD.Value) + (0x564 * (uint)camosoldierUD.Value), new byte[] { 0x0A });
        }
        if (weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            PS3.SetMemory(Offsets.WeaponCamo + (0x80 * (uint)camoclassUD.Value) + (0x564 * (uint)camosoldierUD.Value), new byte[] { 0x0B });
        }
        if (weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            PS3.SetMemory(Offsets.WeaponCamo + (0x80 * (uint)camoclassUD.Value) + (0x564 * (uint)camosoldierUD.Value), new byte[] { 0x0C });
        }
```

As you see a specific byte is assigned to each item, I was wondering how I would still do this but in a loop?

Thanks

Comment: Can you Describe what will be the answer of `0X0F + 4`?

Comment: I mean if selectedIndex is 4 then what will be your answer? I am trying to understand the bit calculation so that I could try to answer your question.

Comment: @Vishal The code is the same except the byte is 0x0E this time and it will assign that to the offset "WeaponCamo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex` to `0x0A`

```
if(weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
{
    PS3.SetMemory(Offsets.WeaponCamo + (0x80 * (uint)camoclassUD.Value) + (0x564 * (uint)camosoldierUD.Value), new byte[] { 0x0A + weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex  });
}
```

OR use a lookup table (in fact an array)

```
var values = new byte[]{0x0f,0x6a};

if(weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex>-1)
{
    PS3.SetMemory(Offsets.WeaponCamo + (0x80 * (uint)camoclassUD.Value) + (0x564 * (uint)camosoldierUD.Value), new byte[] { values[weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex] });
}
```

Comment: You also should check that the selected index is valid before doing this

Comment: The only issue that there is would be that sometimes the byte could be completely random. So e.g. 0x0F then next it would be 0x6A and so on

Comment: @TobyCook then use an array `new byte[]{0x0f,0x6a};` where the index to array is `weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create a function that sets the memory and then just call it with an index.

```
public void SetMemory(int index)
{ 
    if(index >= 0)
    {
        PS3.SetMemory(Offsets.WeaponCamo + (0x80 * (uint)camoclassUD.Value) + (0x564 * (uint)camosoldierUD.Value), new byte[] { (0x0A + index)});
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
    SetMemory(weaponcamCombo.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: I have the bytes set up in a class as well as they are random bytes. Would there be any way to use them from the class in the indexing?